# OleDbDataAdapter does not imports Selected column

Tags: c#, .net, excel, oledb, oledbdataadapter

I Use the OleDbDataAdapter to read values from incomming Excel (xls) file. My connection looks like:

```
string connectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + dataFilePath + ";Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=NO;IMEX=1;TypeGuessRows=0;ImportMixedTypes=Text;';";
```

However I have problem with case, when the incoming file column has selection. It means when I open the original file, I see that the entire first column (except the firs cell which is a column header) is selected. This causes the problem for me, because he OleDbDataAdapter skips this entire column to import to the DataTable.
Has anybody any suggestions for solving this problem? Thanks in advance.

UPDATE: If I open the file, and remove the selection (just by clicking with mouse on some cell) and save the file, the reading works good. But this is some workaround, I don't want to check for selection and resave the file each time. It should be some solution for this case...

Comment: Does your imported file has to be an Excel file? You can use OLEDB to read data from a CSV file, so either you can convert your XLS file, or ask the provider to change the format.

Comment: Yes, It had to be Excel file. We can't push the provide to change the format as other consumers are also using this format too.